# Ruby: NoMethodError: undefined method when Mutating Instance Variable

Tags: ruby, methods, instance

I am writing a program that will reshuffle passengers on the bus. I want to record how many shuffles it takes to re-order the seating on the bus. Thought I had it, but I cannot change `self.reshuffle_count`. How do I access `@reshufffle_count` from the method `reshuffle_seating`

```
class MagicBus < Array

  attr_writer :seating

  def seating
    @seating || []
  end

  def reshuffle_count
    @reshuffle_count || 0
  end

def reshuffle_seating
    max_passengers = self.seating.max
    popular_seat = self.seating.max
    pop_seat_indx = self.seating.find_index(popular_seat)
    reshuffle_num = 0
    self.seating.rotate!(pop_seat_indx)
    while popular_seat > 1 do 
      self.seating.each_with_index do |seat, index|
      if index != 0
        self.seating[index] = self.seating[index] +1
        popular_seat = popular_seat -1
      else
        reshuffle_num = reshuffle_num +1
        p reshuffle_num
      end
      end
    end
    self.seating.rotate!(pop_seat_indx*-1)
    self.seating[pop_seat_indx] = popular_seat
    self.reshuffle_count = reshuffle_num   
  end
end

class TestMagicBusSeating < MiniTest::Test
def test_reshuffle_seating_instance1
    bus = MagicBus.new
    bus.seating = [0,2,7,0]
    bus.reshuffle_seating
    assert_equal([2, 4, 1, 2], bus.seating)
    assert_equal(5, bus.reshuffle_count)
  end
end
```

Error Message is

```
Error:
TestMagicBusSeating#test_reshuffle_seating_instance1:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reshuffle_count=' for []:MagicBus
Did you mean?  reshuffle_count
    magic_bus.rb:99:in `reshuffle_seating'
    magic_bus.rb:217:in `test_reshuffle_seating_instance1'
```

Comment: Inheriting from array here is an unusual thing to do. What's the intent? It looks like you don't even use that angle.

Comment: You probably mean `@reshuffle_count = ...` as you don't have an `attr_writer` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `reshuffle_count='

That means you are missing a `setter`. You have the getter defined `def reshuffle_count` but no setter.

```
class MagicBus < Array

  attr_writer :seating

  def seating
    @seating || []
  end

  def reshuffle_count=(value)
    @reshuffle_count=value
  end

  def reshuffle_count
    @reshuffle_count || 0
  end
  .....
```

Or as @tadman pointed out, `attr_writer :resuffle_count`

Comment: This generates....
`Error:
TestMagicBusSeating#test_reshuffle_seating_instance1:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reshuffle_count' for []:MagicBus
Did you mean?  reshuffle_count=
    magic_bus.rb:219:in `test_reshuffle_seating_instance1'`

Comment: Updated the answer with the class.

Comment: I didn't need `def reshuffle_count=(value)
    @reshuffle_count=value
  end` Otherwise that solved the error

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you can also directly access the instance variables inside other methods of the same class.

```rb
class MagicBus < Array

  def reshuffle_count
    @reshuffle_count || 0
  end

  def reshuffle_seating
    ...
    @reshuffle_count = reshuffle_num
  end 
end
```

Note that, if you define,
`attr_writer :resuffle_count` then MagicBus instances can also read/write the variable outside of the class.

```
magic_bus = MagicBus.new
magic_bus.resuffle_count # valid
```

Unless you put the `attr_writer :resuffle_count` inside a private scope.

```rb
class MagicBus < Array
  ...
  def reshuffle_seating
    ... 
    reshuffle_count = reshuffle_num   
  end

  private

  attr_writer :resuffle_count
end
```

Now `resuffle_count` can only be accessed inside the class.